# Visual Studio 2010 Winforms keeps forgetting resources

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, icons, embedded-resource

For some reason on my current project I create my resource file via the project properties, add a load of existing images. Then go to add these images to menu items, save it. At this point everything looks fine and the images are all mapped correctly.

However once I close the designer for that form, then open it up I get the error dialog saying:

`The type 'My.Project.Properties.Resources' has no property named 'icon_plus'.`

The annoying thing is that if you follow it through to the code there is no error, it compiles fine:

```
this.newToolStripMenuItem.Image = global::My.Project.Properties.Resources.icon_plus;
```

I have tried deleting all resources and removing the resource file from the project, completely closing down the IDE then re-loading it. I have moved the location of the files, but I am just out of ideas and it is REALLY starting to grate with about 10 forms and controls which each give me this error them remove the icons from the UI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one of those VERY annoying issues, which I would never have thought about until I got another issue which caused me to change things.

It *seems* to have been down to the application using the Client Profile for .net 4 rather than just the default .net 4 runtimes. Once I changed this over this issue stopped and my other missing namespace issue which recently arose went away.

Answer (score 17):

Take a look at project references, and remove the reference to self.

Comment: Excellent! This solution worked for me. I was having the same problem as Grofit. I looked at References and saw that my project was referencing itself. I don't know how that happened as I don't recall ever putting it there myself. Does VS auto-add this reference or prompt the user for it? Seems like a fairly known bug or was it just me?

Comment: @DerekW I haven't been able to determine why or when Visual Studio does this, I can only guess it's some kind of bug.

Comment: Perfect! This solution also worked for me! Not to mention, it apparently improved the load time of my application by a great deal! This of course may be a coincidence.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what worked for me. (Tried everything posted and no joy.)

When I first started the projects the default `namespace` specified in the projects properties was `MyProject`. (so most of my classes looked like `namespace` `MyProject{ public class foo{} }`

Later I changed the namespace for my classes from `MyProject` to `CompanyName.MyProject`
This is also when the problem occurred.

In my case, I had to go back to the `Project Properties` and change the actually entry
in `Default namespace` to `CompanyName.MyProject`

Bang, no more problem.

Answer (score 2):

Its most likely to do with a Namespace conflict.

Double check all namespaces in the project, VS likes to do 'ProjectName.FolderName'.  If it auto-changes one of the classes/resource files in your Icon folder to ProjectName.Icon, it may conflict with a class/struct name.

Funny thing is that the application builds..

Comment: I thought this, but when I deleted everything (folders containing resources, the actual resource file and any reference to and from it) then recreated it, I re-added them externally from the project and let it put them wherever it wanted to. Still same problem, and there is no Resource namespace in the solution other than the one it creates itself for said resources.

Comment: +1 if you can, try to strip it down (into a bare bones project) until the problem is clearly visible.

Answer (score 1):

I ran across the same issue.  VS wouldn't load any of the form objects.  I tried all of the other approaches with no outcome.

Previously I changed all of the Private global variables to Public properties.

```
public Textbox exampleTextBox { get; set; }
```

I did this for multiple reasons, but the designer view doesn't like it. I believe it must have some parsing issues.

the object must be a global variable not a property.

```
public Textbox exampleTextBox;
```

This fixed my designer view.

Answer (score 1):

**I have found another way**

Move initialization form code in private methode like below

```
private void FormInitialize(){/*Your code here*/}
```

In form constructor use it like this

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        FormInitialize();
    }
```

And from Button, menuItem or other call methode like this

```
    private void ChangeCultureToFrench_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("fr");
        this.Controls.Clear();
        this.InitializeComponent();
        FormInitialize();
    }
```

I hope this help ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I have come accross this error before. It arose for me when I added a resource, and then took it away or ammended it. The only way I found I could get around this problem was by opening up the .csproj file and looking for the .ico that it is giving the error for and removing it. Your looking for

```
<ItemGroup>
    <None Include="Resources\SomeResource.ico" />
</ItemGroup>
```

After this, save the file. Open the solution and re-add. Hopefully this will work for you. Note however, this is not the ideal solution.

*Edit:*

OK. So this did not solve your problem. Go into the solution folder and navigate to the 'Properties' folder. inside you will see a file called resources. Open it and try to find your problematic file name

```
<data name="YourNamedIco" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">
    <value>..\Resources\SomeResource.ico;System.Drawing.Bitmap, System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, 
         Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a</value> 
</data>
```

if you do find it, remove this, save.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I have removed all of these sorts of references while I was removing everything else, it made no difference, once I re-opened the project and added them back in via the VS existing file dialog it just acted the same way...

Comment: Again I have tried manually tinkering with this file, have manually deleted the resources.resx or whatever it is called and then created it from scratch and added them one by one to see if they are working... none of them work :( I was just wondering if it was a VS2010 bug? I will try making a new project and seeing if it happens then.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as you, though the "solution" I used may not even be called as such. I did know I add a few setup projects to it, and removed it, alongside fiddling with the build actions of a few images.

The solution I used? Delete the current project, and revert to the most recent made backup, which did not have the issue. Of course, this would only work if you make backups of your project solutions.

If you do make backups of your project solutions, only try this method as a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the other answers by none of them worked.

What finally just seemed to work for me was doing "Unload Project" by right clicking on your project, then "Reload Project". Before checking if my `.cs [Design]` worked yet, I then also renamed my project to something else by right clicking the project in the Solution Explorer then clicking "rename".

Don't ask me why this worked...

Answer (score 0):

Open Resources.resx file and add new image and then build your solution/project. Error will disappear.